# Xcode, why some constraints are automatically added?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, constraints

Let's say i want to align a button (Delete) on the right border of every different device (3.5, 4, 4.5 inch etc.)

[image]

Should be very simple but, when i add a constraint to the right border:

[image]

New constraints are automatically added and i can see a dashed border rectangle on the top right of the view (which means that my button has been moved to the top.):

[image]

Why?? I don't need to add tons of contraints, i just want to align the button to the right and stay in the same position for every device.

Comment: Try centering it horizontally. (control drag from the button to the right side of the window and you should see that option)

Comment: @NewEngland I assume you mean vertically.

Comment: @nghrif nope. horizontally. That'll make the orange outline disappear

Comment: No it won't.  I don't think it will... it's also an unnecessary constraint.  The problem that IB is highlighting here is that it doesn't know the height or Y position (vertical constraints).

Comment: Hi NewEngland. I have tried and the orange outline disappear, you are right, but the position of the element is moving to the top-right anyway :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the red outline in the upper right corner because now that you've added *one* constraint Auto Layout needs additional constraints in order to know that you also want the button further down on the screen. You can accomplish this by also setting a constraint for position from the top, for instance.

Comment: I agree with that, thanks. The problem is, I was trying to find a way not to set the position from the top

Comment: You cannot "not set the position from the top". If you set _any_ constraints you must set _all_ of them (that is, enough to disambiguate completely). That is how layout with constraints work. This has nothing to do with Xcode; it has to do with what constraints are.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is not "adding tons of constraints". It is doing what you said to do - and showing you that the results of doing that would be a disaster. It is telling *you* that *you* need to add more constraints or you'll have a mess on your hands.

Basically, as soon as you add *one* constraint to position/size an object, you must add *sufficient* constraints to position/size it *unambiguously*.

(Notice the warning/error messages in the document structure pane at the left, not shown in your screen shots. They are telling you something!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know Xcode is just trying to help but should not move the position of the elements without my confirmation. The problem is that all the buttons with image that I have get bigger and it's almost impossible to create a nice design for every design.

Comment: Listen to what I'm saying. Xcode didn't move anything. _You_ moved it. Xcode is _showing_ you what you've done, as a warning. As long as you see dotted outlines like this, _your constraints are ambiguous_ and you are in serious trouble.

Comment: I don't agree. I have some buttons with images, I set up the width and height from the size inspector, I add a constraint with fixed width and height. Should be fine right? No, because the buttons are getting bigger if the simulator is iPhone6. In iPhone 5s everything is fine. Tell me what is the reason.

Comment: That would be a completely different question, @Marco. It has nothing to do with this question. Don't leech this page with new questions in comments. Ask a new question! _This_ page is about the question you _did_ ask.

Comment: You don't get to "agree" or "disagree" about how constraints work. How they work is how they work!

Comment: my question was just an example to highlight how poor are the constraint options and how complicated they are when you have to deal with many elements and many devices. Thanks anyway for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You added constraints for the x position of the button. Now you have to add constraints for the y position of the button. An easy way that will most of the time work is to go into the auto layout bar at the bottom and clicking the third icon from the left. Then you click either add missing constraints or reset to suggested constraints.